# JSF 2.0 Lifecycle listner

Tags: jsf-2

How will i write My custom lifecycle listner for **jsf 2**
For jsf 1.2 BalusC has provided good tutorial but in JSF2 we do not have faces-config.xml
can we use faces-config.xml.if yes can you please provide me sample..If no then how do we register listners in jsf 2.0 

**Thanks A Lot**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still create the file faces-config.xml and put in WEB-INF folder. The header of your faces-config.xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
              version="2.0">

   // Your configuration here

</faces-config>
```

Notice that the version is now 2.0.